# UncaughtErrorEvent stops SWF loading with flash player 10.0

Tags: actionscript, flash

I have included the Uncaughterrorevent handler for the LoaderInfo. Which worked fine in my actionscript project.

That was until I attempted to use a browser with a FP version of 10,0. This then fails to load the SWF unless i take out all references to UncaughtErrorevent.

Has anyone had this?

I did try only adding the error handler if flash player 10,1 > is installed. But still doesn't work. Even having a reference to UncaughtErrorEvent as parameter in a function causes the SWF not to load.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer: UncaughtErrorEvent was introduced in flash player version 10.1.

If you are using an older version of the player, it is not cromulent actionscript. So you have to use either Player 10.1 as your lowest required player version for your project, or you have to remove it.

In the adobe documentation there is a line near the top:
"Runtime Versions:  Flash Player 10.1, AIR 2"

You can find it for any actionscript call to see if it is supported by your player version.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html